# Making bar plot of different clusters

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart, k-means, unsupervised-learning

I am currently learning K-means, so now I am writing a program in Python to determine different clusters of text that are similar to each other.

So now I got the results for two different clusters (using some fictional words but everything else is the same).

```
print(dfs)  = [           features     score
0  America 0.577350
1            new 0.288675
2        president 0.288675
3          Biden 0.288675
,       features     score
0       Corona 0.593578
1  COVID-19 0.296789
2     research 0.296789
3    health 0.158114]
```

And dfs is the following type

```
type(dfs) = list
```

And the following:

```
type(dfs[0]) = pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

But how can I easily create bar plots for each cluster in dfs where you see the score attached to each word?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `dfs` list to access individual dataframes, then, use `df.plot.bar` with `x='features` and `y='score'` as arguments to plot the bar chart relative to that same dataframe. Use the resulting axis from plot function to attach the scores for each bar in the `features` column. For that, iterate over each patch from the bar plot axis using the `x` from the rectangle anchor point and the `height` of the bar as arguments to the [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.annotate.html) function.

```py
...
...

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(dfs))
for num, df in enumerate(dfs):
    ax = df.plot.bar(x='features', y='score', ax=axes[num])
    for p in ax.patches:
        ax.annotate(f'{p.get_height():.4f}', xy=(p.get_x() * 1.01, p.get_height() * 1.01))
    axes[num].tick_params(axis='x', labelrotation=30)
    axes[num].set_title(f'Dataframe #{num}')

plt.show()
```

[image: cluster_barplot]